# How to rebuild database before testing using gradle?

Tags: database, postgresql, unit-testing, initialization, gradle

I've my project with two subprojects and most of my tests depend on a database connection. As postgres is the target db I also want to use that in my junit tests. Before starting the testsuite (all tests) I would like to (re)build and initialize the database with some some values.

From commandline i can do `psql -h host -d database -u usrname -f filename` before doing `gradle build`.

How can i incorporate this in the gradle test task? (I'm using junit 4, if that matters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution1:

Define a 'psql' task in your **root** project

```
task psql (type:Exec) { 
    commandLine 'psql', '-h', 'host', '-d', 'database', '-u', 'usrname', '-f' , 'filename'    
}
```

If you want this task to be run only once, add the following in your **root** project

```
test.dependsOn psql
```

If you want this task to be run for every subproject, add the following in the respective **subprojects**

```
test.dependsOn(rootProject.tasks.psql)
```

### Solution2:

use [configuration injection](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec%3ainjected_configuration). Simply add the following in your **root** project:

```
subprojects {
    task psql (type:Exec) { 
        commandLine 'psql', '-h', 'host', '-d', 'database', '-u', 'usrname', '-f' , 'filename'    
    }
    test.dependsOn(psql)
}
```

### Solution3:

use methods iso tasks, but I guess that's less 'gradle'. 
See [inherited_properties_and_methods](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec%3ainherited_properties_and_methods) for more info

Comment: thanks, I'm trying this and it works but.. the java plugin applies to 2 subprojects, the test task is invoked for both projects and the psql task is executed once. I think I need to put this in the 'root project' the one every other project is dependent on.

Comment: Do you want the psql task to be executed twice (once for each java project) ?